# Proving that $\sqrt{S^{-1}I}=S^{-1}\sqrt{I}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

> I have to prove that $\sqrt{S^{-1}I}=S^{-1}\sqrt{I}$.

The part $\sqrt{S^{-1}I}\supset S^{-1}\sqrt{I}$ is easier, but I am stuck at the other part.

Let $\frac{a}{s}\in S^{-1}A$ s.t. for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $(\frac{a}{s})^n=\frac{a^n}{s^n}\in S^{-1}I$.

I am confused about definitions, because I am beginner: this means that $a^n\in I$ and $s^n\in S^{-1}$? If yes, then is easy, but I do not know if I can state this. Only know that there is $\frac{i}{t}\in S^{-1}I$ s.t. $(a^nt-is^n)u=0$, for some $u\in S$.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: No, that does not mean what you said. Instead from $a^ntu=s^niu$ you get $a^n(tu)\in I$. Then $(atu)^n\in I$, and thus $atu\in\sqrt I$. Now write $a/s=(atu)/(stu)$, and you are done.

Comment: Thank you so much. Wouldn't you like to post as answer?